# Permission to print a parallel Bible

Tags: bible

Praise the Lord.
I have recently published the Tamil Bible in romanised English (or transliteration) to enable the Tamil speaking diaspora who cannot read the Tamil script but are well versed in the English script to enable them to read the Bible  in Tamil.
However, I have noticed that most of these people do not understand the menaing of some words in Tamil. To overcome this challenge I am planning to publish a Bible that carries the transliteration version (that I already have completed after 4 years) side by side with an English version.
I need your advice on which version I can use with no or minimum cost. I would prefer to use NKJV but the cost is prohibitive.
Please advise. Blessings.

Comment: I would recommend talking to one of the Bible Societies or translation agencies (like Wycliffe) in India. If your goal is to help people understand then don't pick the NKJV!!! If they don't understand, **revise your Tamil translation**.

Comment: Not a duplicate: question does not require that the translation be free, just low-cost.